# По IDE Eclipse, горячие клавиши

Tags: java, eclipse

Есть в Eclipse горячие клавиши комментирования кода(строки, блока)
Так вот, они не работают. Никак. Как я их смотрел: выделяю блок кода - ПКМ(правая кнопка мыши) - source - и там у каждого действия подписаны горячие клавиши. Конкретно для блока кода я нажимал <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>. В чем может быть беда?

Comment: Раскладка в момент нажатия какая была выбрана - русская или английская?

Comment: @AlexChermenin да, нашел, на английской раскладке...спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у меня работает <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> а вообще их можно посмотреть в preferennces -> keys